# Power shell For Loop not Looping

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, windows-firewall

So the output works fine but I'm having an issue with it only outputing the last line it runs. Is there anyway to check for loops to test in the future?

but i have a list of ip address and im trying to check if the firewall in windows is enabled or disabled.
They are on one LARGE (300+ workgroup). Any help in getting this to loop properly would be appreciated. Security and other things are not a concern cause i have other scripts that run fine. And i dont get any errors. just the single output.

ive already tried moving the array and that didn't help. im thinking it could be the PSCustomObject part as i'm just starting to learn these. Or could it be my input and output formats are different and that's causing issues??

```
clear
$ComputerList = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DavidsScripts\TurnOffFirewall\input.txt
$Status = @(
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {

netsh -r $Computer advfirewall show currentprofile state})[3] -replace 'State' -replace '\s' 


$Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Computer = $Computer
    Firewall = $Status
}

Write-Output $Object
$Object | Export-Csv -Path "C:\FirewallStatus.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your `$Status` contains the `ForEach` meaning you will only get the last run `$Computer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous code was not escaping the loop and was only adding the last computer in the loop to the object.

The best way I have found, is to make a temp object and add it to an array list then export that. Much nicer.

```
$ComputerList = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DavidsScripts\TurnOffFirewall\input.txt
$collectionVariable = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {
    # Create temp object
    $temp = New-Object System.Object
    # Add members to temp object
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $Computer
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Firewall" -Value $((netsh -r $Computer advfirewall show currentprofile state)[3] -replace 'State' -replace '\s')
    # Add the temp object to ArrayList
    $collectionVariable.Add($temp)
}

Write-Output $collectionVariable
$collectionVariable | Export-Csv -Path "C:\FirewallStatus.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your solution is effective, but unless you need PowerShell version 2 compatibility, I suggest using the `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntax for creating custom objects - as used in the question - which is both more readable and performs better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a streamlined, functional version of your code, using a single pipeline:

```bsh
Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DavidsScripts\TurnOffFirewall\input.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Computer = $_
      Firewall = (-split ((netsh -r $_ advfirewall show currentprofile state) -match '^State'))[-1]    
    }
  } | Export-Csv -Path C:\FirewallStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note:

- No intermediate variables are needed; each computer name read from the input file is processed one by one, and each custom object constructed based on it is sent to the output CSV file.
- The command for extracting the firewall status from `netsh`'s output was made more robust in order to extract the state information based on the line *content* (regex `^State`, i.e., a line starting with `State`) rather than a line *index* (`[3]`); the unary form of `-split` splits the line of interest into tokens by whitespace, and index `[-1]` extracts the last token, which is the state value.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your `foreach` loop ended *before* `$Object` was constructed, so you ended up constructing just *1* object to send to the output file with `Export-Csv`.
- If you had formatted your code properly, that fact would have been more obvious; try using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), which offers automatic formatting via the `>Format Document` (<kbd>Shift+Alt+F</kbd>) command.